# Checking/unchecking checkboxes based on returned database values

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I am trying to get a checkbox to be checked based on values returned from a database. So far I'm getting the correct "Y" or "N" values up to my controller layer, but the checkbox is not being checked/unchecked as it should. I tried the following but it doesn't work, I'm thinking that something is wrong with the test scenario.

```
<td  class="normalTD " width="4%" style="white-space: nowrap" align="left" >
<c:choose>
<c:when test="detail[${loop.index}].flag eq 'Y'">
    <input type="checkbox" path="detail[${loop.index}].flag" id="detail[${loop.index}].flag" checked="checked" />
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
    <input type="checkbox" path="detail[${loop.index}].flag" id="detail[${loop.index}].flag" checked="" />
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
</td>
```

Loop before checkbox:

```
<c:set var="detail" value="${commandObj.detail}" scope="page" />
    <c:if test="${!empty commandObj.detail}">
        <c:forEach items="${commandObj.detail}" var="detail" varStatus="loop">
            <c:if test="${!empty detail.cd}">
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I have a checkbox, I want it to be either checked or unchecked based on what value I'm getting from my database. So if the value is "Y" I want the checkbox to be checked, otherwise it'll stay unchecked. This will all be happening on a page load, not on a form submit.

Comment: Chechbox is checked or unchecked depends on the field value you use, but you either didn't use a tag or value of the inbox, so the value won't be rendered ant it won't be checked.

Comment: Which tags do you mean?

Comment: The tags I'm working with.

Comment: How  is the detail variable defined? Show us the beginning of the loop (where all the variables are defined)

Comment: @dsp_user I updated my post with the loop part.

Comment: Since the variable detail already represents (or should represent) a single list item, I'd expect the test to be of the following form:   test="detail.flag eq 'Y'" (detail is not the list but rather an item in the list). I could be more specific if you need more help.

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit old so I suppose you have found a solution but if not :

You propably need to check the flag one the `detail` var from the forEach loop, `detail` is not the `commandObj.detail` but on of the instance in this list/array. You should rename `commandObj.detail` into `commandObj.details` to make the difference between an instance and a collection ;)

Also, you should use a ternary condition to have a more readable code. The condition is simple.

```
<c:forEach items="${commandObj.detail}" var="detail" varStatus="loop">
    <c:if test="${!empty detail.cd}">
        <input type="checkbox" 
               path="detail[${loop.index}].flag"
               id="detail[${loop.index}].flag" 
               ${"detail.flag eq 'Y'" ? "checked" : ""} 
        />
```

The checked attributes doesn't need a value, just to be present or not.

I can't test it write now, if there is a mistake and I forgot to check it tonigth, thanks to notify me. :) **(If this line is present, I have forgotten ;) )**